# How do I play sounds with C++ on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, audio

I am updating a C++ program written twenty years ago to run scientific experiments that involve the precise starting and stopping of sounds. The program also needs to be able to control playback volume, pause sounds or start them at a designated position, loop sounds a specified number of times, and control channel mapping.

The researchers hope to run the program on a modern Mac OS X, but I have never done any development on a Mac before. What is the simplest way to accomplish the above goals in C++ on a Mac?

`CoreAudio` seems way too complicated. `NSSound` seems to have all the features I want, but as far as I can tell it is only available in Objective-C? Is it possible to mix Objective-C with C++? Or should I be looking at using the `QuickTime` SDK?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can mix Objective-C and C++.  It's a hybrid language called [Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B).  If `NSSound` has all of the features you need, go for it; if not, CoreAudio is the way to go.  It will be much more challenging to set up and integrate larger libraries such as QuickTime, OpenAL, or FMOD.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can mix Objective-C and C++. Objective-C is just C with some stuff added on, and that same stuff can be layered on top of C++ instead to get Objective-C++ (in particular Objective-C++ doesn't have C features that are in Objective-C but not C++).

Using CoreAudio directly may be useful if you need very low latency.

Another option may be OpenAL, which is available as just another built-in framework, OpenAL.framework.